# Asp.net Web Api 2 - Which Json properties were passed to my controller?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

I have a customer dto model - see example below - it has a lot of properties.

```
  public class CustomerDtoModel
    {
        public string OrganisationName { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateOfLastPurchase { get; set; }
        // other properties not shown ....
    }
```

Json is passed to my web api controller and bound to the model to update existing data e.g.

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("{id:guid}")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateCustomer(Guid id, [FromBody] CustomerDtoModel updatedCustomer)
{
    // do the update 
     return Ok();
}
```

As there a lot of properties I want to allow people using the api to only specify the properties in their Json they want to change - e.g. only changing LastName from Smith to Jones - any property that is not in the Json will not update the existing data.

I also need to keep the strongly typed model names in the controller actions so they can appear in my Swagger documentation.

My problem is around clearing existing values

It is acceptable to pass in the Json an empty a string to clear string and 0 for numerics, but I need a way of allowing dates to be reset to null.  I could say passing a date of 1/1/0001 will set the existing value to null - but that is clunky and I hoped to find a better solution.

For example in MVC I have used a FormCollection parameter on my controller methods to know which fields / properties had been posted back to controller so I can avoid changing fields which are not affected the update.

Is there a similarly neat solution that would work in a Web Api?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're probably looking for a *PATCH*.
Maybe this can help:
http://techbrij.com/http-patch-request-asp-net-webapi

Comment: Thanks for the response - PATCH is probably the right solution - I was trying to keep things simple for people consuming the API - as PATCH requests are more complex to construct than PUT